# JS/JSON 'Desktop Notifications'

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-chrome, notifications

I am no coding expert in any way, but I have coded a neat little thing to tell if a Node is up/down, I use  some PHP script and chuck it into a table (It can be seen below, and yes , I know it is probably very messy, but I am new to this). I am now looking to add desktop notifications to tell the user when a Node pings back as down, and I understand that I will need to use JSON for this? But that is what I am stuck on. Do bear in mind that I already have a permissions code to ask for permissions to Enable Notifications :) www.samaustin.nn.pe/nitrostatus.php

```
<?php 

$connection = @fsockopen("IPHere", "PortHere", $errno, $errstr, "2");

if(!$connection) {
echo '<tr class="danger">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><i class="icon-remove-circle"></i>  Node Down! We are working on this!</td>

      </tr>';
} else {
    echo '<tr class="success">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><i class="icon-ok-circle"></i>  Node Up!</td>

      </tr>';
}


?>
```

Comment: PHP has `json_encode`

Comment: Sorry but I simply do not understand this. Is there any chance you could do an example using the base code I have created?